# HTTPS localhost port-forwarding to Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding, https, localhost

I am running Virtualbox on my host (Windows 7 Professional 64-bit) with NAT and port-forwarding set from localhost to Virtualbox (guest Mint 17.3 Mate). If i call http://localhost:5000, I can access my services in Virtualbox, for which I have set port-forwarding on that port.

Is it possible to call https://localhost:5000 and that it translates to Virtualbox port forwarding again? Do I need to set up something in hosts file or do I need to setup something in Virtualbox itself? My current port forwarding settings are as shown below.

Reason: My webpage is running under HTTPS and if I call service on http it gets blocked.

Best regards.

[image]

**-------------- EDIT ----------------**

So how I ended up at the end. Since we are using nodejs, I wrote a nodejs script, that runs proxy server on https on different ports and proxies the calls to the http localhost on the same ports. This is however not a best practice, but it is intended only for developing purposes.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! It would help to include information such as what your current forwarded ports are. Do you just have Host:5000 forwarded to Guest:5000? You can also take a screenshot of the port forwarding page and include that if you have lots of rules or more complex rules that would be hard to type out.

Comment: OK. Here is link to port-forwarding settings: [link](https://picload.org/image/rlplwrar/port-forwarding.png). Currently I have just 5111 -> 5111 and 9999 -> 8888, so I want to be able to call localhost with https and not http.